# Combine Excel files columnwise by Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need to create an overview table for the results of a survey. Data (answers) is stored in multiple Excel files and I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve it by using Power Query.

All the files (questionnaires) are saved in the same folder and have exactly the same structure. They consist of two columns, while the first column lists the questions (Q) and the second column - the answers (A), e.g.:

Table 1:

| Questions | Answers |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | A11 |
| Q2 | A12 |
| Q3 | A13 |

Table 2:

| Questions | Answers |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | A21 |
| Q2 | A22 |
| Q3 | A23 |

The resulting overview table should look like:

| Questions | Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | A11 | A21 |
| Q2 | A12 | A22 |
| Q3 | A13 | A23 |

My Power Query skills are rather limited, I manage to append single files/tables below each other, but what I rather need is a kind of columnswise combination of tables.

Your help is much appreciated!
Max

Comment: Is this just a single [merge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-power-query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d#__step_1__merge) or are you trying to combine a lot more than two tables?

Comment: If they *have exactly the same structure*, how do you know which is `Table1` and which `Table2`?

Comment: Thank you for your questions! The file names are different, e.g. "AnswersMax.xlsx" and "MySurveyAnswers.xlsx" and each file contains exactly one table. The structure of each table (amount of rows, columns, format) is, indeed, exactly the same, but the answers might be different. What I'm trying is to collect all the answers from different files in one single overview table. Thank you! Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed like this..

**Step-1** Data (menu) > Get & Transform > New Query > From file > from Folder

**Step-2** Combine & Transform

**Step-3** pivot on `source` column (Advanced options - second column and don't aggregate)

You'll get desired view.

See the following screenshots for help

[image]